# JSON respone from CURL request from HTTP API - HTML transform

Tags: api, parsing, curl, json

I am able to send the CURL request to a test http API and getting the response as well.

My CURL request is like:

```
$request = "";
$param['auth-userid'] = '449735';
$param['api-key'] = 'apikey';
$param['domain-name'] ='sambalpurodisha';
$param['tlds']='com';
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {$request.= $key ."=".urlencode($val);    
$request .="&";}
$request=substr($request,0,strlen($request)- 1 );
$url = "https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?".$request;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

I am getting a response like:
**{"sambalpurodisha.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"}}**

Now I have tried everything to format the result in more readable manner like
Domain - sambalpurodisha.com is available for purchase.

I have tried number of suggestions here at stack, but none worked for me. A direction where I can look for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to decode the returned JSON string as either a JSON object or an associative array, then iterate through it:

```
$rawJSON = '{"sambalpurodisha.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"}}';

$jsonArray = json_decode($rawJSON, true);
foreach($jsonArray as $key => $val) {

    echo 'Domain: ' . $key . '  status: ' . $val['status'] . "\n";

}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know what value will be there in the variables. domain-name can be anything, status->value and classkey -> value will keep changing. so $rawjason = to have have the expected variables.

Comment: That should work fine. Just assign the response you get back from cURL to rawJSON. The hardcoded string here is simply intended to be an example.

Comment: Ok I have tried adding 

$rawJSON=$result;
 
and then $jsonAraay =...........................}
But I am getting the same result i.e.
'{"sambalpurodisha.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"}}'; and not the expected result.

Do I need to do anything different.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. I can't give you a full code sample, since the URL in your question above (https://test.httpapi.com) doesn't appear to be accepting requests. When you try the parsing code I supplied, what exactly is getting echoed to the console?

Comment: Right I think I have messed up my code  hence not getting the result. Now it's working fine as expected.